# django and postgresql: Get SQLSTATE from django database Exception

Tags: django, postgresql

Is there a way to get the SQLSTATE code from a django ProgrammingError or OperationalError? All I can find now is the "message", which is locale-dependent.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the exception object with e.g `dir()`?

Answer (score 1):

After further research, it appears the only way to get the SQLSTATE is:

```
exception.__cause__.pgcode
```